# system slow after hibernation, it seems like files dont transfer back to RAM

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, ram

i have my main ubuntu OS on a SSD and a swap partinion on HDD. Whenever I boot from hibernation, everything is slower, lags, and for example if i open new chrome windows or even alt+tab to another app , i hear my HDD spinning , making noises. So it seems the files dont transfer back to RAM after hibernation?

swapon -s gives me this:

```
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sdb2             partition  16963580           1461736-2
```

Comment: How much RAM do you have and how big is you SWAP partition?

Comment: @paladin  my RAM is 8gb and swap partition 16gb, i think it's more than enough.

Comment: Please do a `swapon -s` in a terminal and tell us what this command tells you.

Comment: Filename    Type  Size Used Priority
/dev/sdb2                               partition 16963580 1461736-2

Answer (score 4):

RAM is much faster than swap. It may happen that after hibernation, not all memory is being copied back to RAM from swap.

Run the command `sudo swapoff -a && sudo swapon -a` to transfer the memory in swap to RAM, and then turn swap on again.

Comment: I agree to Archisman, but usually a hibernating process works like all the RAM is copied into SWAP and at a reboot all the former copied RAM within SWAP is copied back to RAM.

Comment: I wonder can this command be automatically run whenever the system comes from hibernation?

Comment: @slawckaJS I don't know how to do that.

Comment: It's possible via systemd targets, but I don't recommend it.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me! You can check if swap is used with with `free`. In my case swap used ~4GB (~13%) after wakeup from hibernation. After `sudo swapoff -a && sudo swapon -a` ist was 0 and the system was running faster. However, I still looking for a solution to prevent this..